# How to add new value to "auth()" function after login?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am developing a project with Laravel 8.

There are fields such as "us_name", "us_surname" in my Users table. After the user is logged in, I can reach these values by saying "auth()->user()->us_name" etc. So far, no problem.

What I want to do is add some values here that are not in my table. For example, after logging in, combining the first and last name and adding a new field such as "us_fullname" and accessing it as "auth()->user()->us_fullname". How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this by defining an attribute/accessor in the User model. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 1):

By calling `auth()->user()` you get the Authenticatable model from default guard.

Let's see default config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ]
    ]
];
```

With this default Laravel config, you get:

1. default guard is `web`
2. `web` guard provider (whom provides `Authenticatable`) is `users`
3. `users` provider provide App\Models\User::class
4. App\Models\User implements `Authenticatable` contract

Than, by calling `auth()->user()` - you get the instance of App\Models\User::class or null

### Answer to your question

You can add anything (eg `full_name`) to User model and retrieve this as `auth()->user()->full_name`

Read about [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) - with this you can simply add calculating property:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function getFullNameAttribute()
  {
     return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
  }
}
```